# How to I create a function through a UIButton in the #selector action?

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton

I have a UIButton that has this method run on button down

```
    right.addTarget(sceneto, action: #selector(pageUp), for: .touchDown)
```

However, I was wondering if it is possible to add a function inside this selector method rather than reference a function itself something like this

```
    right.addTarget(sceneto, action: #selector({print("hello world")}), for: .touchDown)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962854/swift-wants-argument-of-selector-to-be-exposed-to-objective-c).

It says:

> Selectors are a feature of Objective-C and can only be used with methods that are exposed to the dynamic Obj-C runtime. You can't have a selector to a pure Swift method.

A method from the Obj-C runtime is called (that's why you need the `@objc` tag for all functions being referenced by selectors) and there is no way to pass closures as selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do this. A selector is just the name of a function, and a closure in swift is a "nameless" or "anonymous" function.

I created an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43923660/3609124) to a similar question that goes into detail about one of the possible situations/workarounds.